# Graph API: Using client_credential grant type to read my or another signed-in user profile

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I thought it would be simple to use Graph API to read my own user profile or another signed-in user profile but no luck so far.

1. I created an Azure app with only the following:
   a) Client Secret
   b) Delegated API permission of User.Read only
2. I then used the following simple code to try to read my own profile but it returned **(400) Bad Request** even though I can see that a token was returned successfully.
3. I was wondering if I could use the same Azure app to read another user's profile provided that a sign-in prompt could be created to switch account.

   Any thoughts?

   [image]

Comment: Could you please edit your question with the code instead of image?

Answer (score 0):

The `me` endpoint requires a user context. You're using the `client credentials` grant type, which is for client apps to use in an app-only context. The app has no awareness of who "me" is, or what "your" profile is because you haven't provided a user.

For the app to read the profiles of other users in the `client credentials` flow, you need to add one of the MS Graph application-type permissions, and send a request to the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` enpoint

[Get user API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: the issue that I have is the API permission of the Azure app is a **delegated User.Read** and not an **application User.Read.All**. So, I was wondering using this app, how can I get a user consent to logon to an account to order to display a signed-on user profile?

Comment: The standard grant type when working with user-authentication and delegated permissions is the `authorization code` flow

Comment: @scottwlang Thanks for the great info.  It has definitely pointed me in the right direction.